# Set dynamic height for TabView in SwiftUI for Custom Views

Tags: ios, dynamic, swiftui, height, tabview

Been trying to figure out how I can dynamically adjust the height of the TabView based on the content.

Here is my code:

```
TabView(selection: $selectedTab){
                
                
                CustomViewOne()
                    .tag(TabHeaderView.Tab.ViewOne)
                
                
                CustomViewTwo()
                    .tag(TabHeaderView.Tab.ViewTwo)
                
                
                CustomViewThree()
                    .tag(TabHeaderView.Tab.ViewThree)
                
            }
            
            .tabViewStyle(PageTabViewStyle(indexDisplayMode: .never))
            .animation(.easeInOut)
```

Due to legal reasons I can't share the screenshot here. But any help will be highly appreciated. Please let me know if you need any code or anything.

I tried getting the height of the custom views by setting a Geometry Reader there but it only returns the height of TabView and not the custom View.

**UPDATE**
For the custom views I have do not have a fixed height, the height of the custom views depends on the data I get from the API.

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

`GeometryReader` is for detecting the size of available space from the parent.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/geometryreader

You have to tell `TabView` some other way what size the `TabView` should give the child. Not the other way around.

```
import SwiftUI
struct ViewProperties: Hashable, Identifiable{
    var id = UUID()
    var height: CGFloat
    var width: CGFloat
}
struct ViewProperties: Hashable, Identifiable{
    var id = UUID()
    var height: CGFloat
    var width: CGFloat
}
struct FlexibleTabView: View {
    @State var selection: ViewProperties?
    @State var views: [ViewProperties] = [ViewProperties(height: 100, width: 100), ViewProperties(height: 150, width: 150), ViewProperties(height: 200, width: 200), ViewProperties(height: 250, width: 250)]
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView{
            TabView(selection: $selection, content: {
                ForEach($views, id:\.id, content: { $view in
                    Rectangle()
                        .border(Color.blue)
                        .foregroundColor(Color.clear)
                        .overlay(
                            VStack{
                            Text(view.height.description)
                            //Change the size of the TabView from within the ChildView
                            Button("change size", action: {
                                view.height = CGFloat(Int.random(in: 100...250))
                                view.width = view.height
                                //Altering the selection seems to be the only way that a TabView redraws
                                selection = view
                            })
                        }
                        ).tag(view as? ViewProperties)
                })
            }).navigationTitle(selection?.height.description ?? "")
                .tabViewStyle(PageTabViewStyle(indexDisplayMode: .never))
                .animation(.easeInOut)
                .onAppear(){
                    selection = views.first!
                }
            
                .frame(width: selection?.height ?? .zero, height: selection?.width ?? .zero, alignment: .center)
        }
        
    }
}
struct FlexibleTabView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        FlexibleTabView()
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answering but the custom views I have do not have a fixed height, the height of the custom views depends on the data I get from the API.

Comment: No problem! Just one approach. Without knowing more it is hard to help.